# Are there generic font families for .NET MAUI

Tags: fonts, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I'm new with .NET MAUI and I ask me if there are a way to use generic font families.
like in CSS

- cursive
- fantasy
- monospace
- serif
- sans-serif

or what is the best approach for this?

Do I really need to include specific fonts in every app? I would prefer a solution that uses the default fonts of the current system.

Thanks for your thoughts and ideas

**Edit1:**
Ahhh, the CSS names seems to work in Android,
[image: sample]
but not in Windows.
How about MacOS?, any experience?

But for Windows, the question remains the same ;-)

Comment: Maui does not provide the API of supported font family list , you can raise the feature request on github : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues .